# Want to sum multiple textboxes into one textbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script to use as a UI for my field members to enter in numerical values of equipment that they need.

I have three textboxes created where they enter the number of items of equipment they need.  I also want to create a total number of items box in this UI so the field members can see how many items they are ordering.  However I cannot figure out how to take the value of the three textboxes and get the sum to come into the totals box.  All I get is either 'undefined' or 'Generic' in the totals box.

Here is the code:

```
function review(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var packageABox = app.createTextBox().setId('packageABox').setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center");
  grid.setWidget(3, 3, packageABox); 

var packageBBox = app.createTextBox().setId('packageBBox').setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center");
  grid.setWidget(4, 3, packageBBox); 

var packageCBox = app.createTextBox().setId('packageCBox').setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center");
  grid.setWidget(5, 3, packageABox); 


var packageTotalBox = app.createTextBox().setId('packageTotalBox').setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center");
  grid.setWidget(7, 3, packageTotalBox); 

return app;
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here... any hints to get packageABox, packageBBox and packageCBox to sum into packageTotalBox???

Thanks!

Comment: please show the code that creates the texBoxes , we need to know if the textBoxes have names from which their value could be retrieved...

Comment: Sorry! I have named the boxes:

.setName('packageABox')

.setName('packageBBox')

.setName('packageCBox')

.setName('packageTotalBox')

Comment: Also, what is the difference between setting the Id and setting the Name??  Do I need to set both of them?

Comment: Using the widget's name you can get its value using e.parameter.name

Answer (score 0):

In a handler function you can get the textBow values, add them and assign the result to the result widget. 
The handler must also have a calBackElement that includes the 3 textBoxes.

The code could be like this:

```
function showTotal(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var packageABox = Number(e.parameter.packageABox);
 var packageBBox = Number(e.parameter.packageBBox);
 var packageCBox = Number(e.parameter.packageCBox);
 var total = packageABox+packageBBox+packageCBox;
 app.getElementById('packageTotalBox').setText(total);// here use the ID of the textBow showing total
 return app;
}
```

If your textBoxes contains anything else than numbers the use a Regex to keep only numbers.
for example, this will wipe out any non digit value and return a number in every case (except if undefined)

```
var x = e.parameter.packageBBox;// for example '45 MPH'
var xAsNumber = Number(x.replace(/\D/g ,'')) ;// delete everything that is not a digit, 45.0 in this example
```

Comment: That seemed to work really well!  I have added a few more of these summations and now am finding that some of them come out as "NaN" in the total box?  Do you know what that means?  Thanks!

Comment: NaN for not a number... is there a letter or a word along with you value ?